# хочу зайти на тестовый сайт через смартфон

Tags: xampp, virtual-hosts, хосты

настроил виртуальные хосты на xampp ,как получить доступ к сайту с других устройств ,подключенных к этой же сети?

Comment: По IP-адресу хоста локальной сети при условии что на него хостится сайт. (Например  `http://10.0.0.2/index.php` ) адрес можно узнать `ipconfig`

Comment: ввожу ip и домен но он показывает папки ,с компа при вводе домена открывается сразу сайт